# How to know the event when `MediaPlayerElement`'s `TimedTextSource` changed

Tags: uwp, media-player

I'm using `MediaPlayerElement`. Now I need to know the event when `TimedTextSource` changed.
But I can't find any docs.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to detect the event of `TimedTextSource` switching, you can listen to the `PresentationModeChanged` event:

```cs
// source is MediaSource
var playBackItem = new MediaPlaybackItem(source);
playBackItem.TimedMetadataTracks.PresentationModeChanged += PresentationChanged;

...

private void PresentationChanged(MediaPlaybackTimedMetadataTrackList sender, TimedMetadataPresentationModeChangedEventArgs args)
{
    string currentLanguage = args.Track.Language;
    // do other things...
}
```

Thanks.